# How to avoid memory leaks with Autofac?

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, memory-leaks, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm trying to better understand IoC/DI, in particular the concept of scopes.

I'm using a sample WPF app (repo [here](https://github.com/InteXX/FriendStorage)) from a [Pluralsight course](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/wpf-mvvm-test-driven-development-viewmodels/table-of-contents) (great service, BTW) and modifying it slightly. Naturally, it worked fine before my changes.

Here's the [original code](https://github.com/InteXX/FriendStorage/blob/master/FriendStorage.UI/App.xaml.vb):

```
Private Sub App_Startup(Sender As App, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
  Dim oBootStrapper As BootStrapper
  Dim oContainer As IContainer
  Dim oMainView As MainView

  oBootStrapper = New BootStrapper
  oContainer = oBootStrapper.GetContainer
  oMainView = oContainer.Resolve(Of MainView)
  oMainView.Show()
End Sub
```

...and here's what I changed it to:

```
Private Sub App_Startup(Sender As App, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
  Dim oBootStrapper As BootStrapper
  Dim oContainer As IContainer
  Dim oMainView As MainView

  oBootStrapper = New BootStrapper
  oContainer = oBootStrapper.GetContainer

  Using oScope As ILifetimeScope = oContainer.BeginLifetimeScope
    oMainView = oScope.Resolve(Of MainView)
    oMainView.Show()
  End Using
End Sub
```

However, this results in an `ObjectDisposedException` when I try to add a new Friend:

[image]

> Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope as it (or one of its parent scopes) has already been disposed.

This all seems to contradict what I'm finding in the [official documentation](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/index.html#basic-concepts-and-terminology):

> It is important to always resolve services from a lifetime scope and not the root container.

That guidance is what led me to introduce the scope in the first place. But if a scope disposes the objects necessary for the application to function, how can we hope to use it? Further, WHY should we use it?

I'm confused. Is my proposed usage incorrect?

**--EDIT--**

To clarify, I'm seeking a solution to the conundrum posed by the official guidance: if we adhere to that our application will fail. But if we don't we risk memory leaks (according to the docs).

What to do?

Comment: Put this another way. A window is not a service.

Comment: Sure, I get it. And I agree. But what about the docs and the requirement to use a LifetimeScope, in order to avoid memory leaks? THAT'S the real problem I'm trying to solve here. The apparent conflict. _**"It is important to always resolve services from a lifetime scope and not the root container."**_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The official guidance is there to help you prevent inadvertent memory leaks.** Since Autofac holds references to disposable things so that it can do the disposing, if you resolve 1000 IDisposable items from the container directly, there's no way to let garbage collection clean them up without disposing the whole container.

This is particularly bad if you're not thinking about that and, say, have a long running app that does occasional work with maybe a database - the work might resolve a disposable database context from the container periodically and even if the calling code executes dispose, the container will hang onto it: memory leak.

However, put that together with the docs about things like singletons. Singletons, even if you resolve them from a child scope, *live at the container root*. Why? Because if you let a scope dispose a shared singleton it would be a problem for everything else needing the singleton.

The "resolve things from a scope" guidance is there to stop folks from shooting themselves in the foot with memory leaks they don't realize they're introducing by only using the container.

If the thing you're resolving is not disposable, AND nothing in the entire dependency chain for that thing is disposable, you're *probably* safe getting it from the container.

The larger lesson here is be diligent with your lifetime scopes and how you want disposal handled. I'm not a WPF guy, but if the main window for the app needs to be resolved and needs to live for the entire duration of the app, it seems like that's a perfect use for a singleton... which wouldn't have been disposed at the end of that lifetime scope and you wouldn't have seen the exception. Autofac also has ways you can opt out of making it do disposal, which stops it from holding those references.

But it's super hard to say "always do this" and "never do that" because, as you see, lifetime scope and disposal is a complex topic. It's important to dig into *why*, and memory management and disposal is why. Getting the lifetimes right on your registered components is equally important for the same reasons.

Comment: Whew... there's a lot to know here. Not only do we need to learn the pattern, but we also need to dive deeply into the nuances of the tool we use to navigate the pattern. That's quite a learning curve (but I'm up for it). This is very interesting, thank you. Favor: could you expand your answer a bit to include a small code snippet illustrating your db context example? (VB or C# is fine.)

Comment: p.s. That works, making `MainView` a singleton. I've got my scope back.

Comment: There's way too much here to capture in a small example. The Autofac docs and examples repo have PLENTY of examples, explanations, and diagrams to try to clarify all this - I would recommend taking some time to really dig in.

Comment: I guess that goes to show how poorly I understand all of this, that I thought a small patch of code could cover it. Pardon me. I also didn't know about the abundance of sample code that you've described—I'll have a look. But I wonder if you couldn't clear something up for me real quick before we wrap this up. As noted, I took your suggestion and made MainView a singleton and that worked. Does that mean, for example, that a db context dependency a level or so down the chain would be properly disposed by that single scope at the top, even though MainView is a singleton? Is that testable somehow?

Comment: Even that isn't a simple question because it's not just "singleton" or "instance per dependency." There are other lifetime you can pick, and the lifetime you pick dictates how disposal will be handled. Please just take time with the docs. I wrote them for a reason.

Comment: OK, will do. Thank you. (Good job, BTW.)

Comment: Toward the end of the [singleton lifetime example](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/index.html#example-singleton-lifetime), there appears to be nowhere that the variable `scope` is declared (maybe I'm missing it). Should that variable be named `child2` instead?

Comment: I submitted a couple of PRs just now.

Comment: As I'm reading through the docs, a thought occurs to me. I'm going to utter some blasphemy, so bear with me for a moment. Given the extensive complexities introduced by IoC/DI—particularly under the concept of scopes—on balance aren't we creating more problems than we're solving? Please advise.

Comment: Unfortunately that's a pretty subjective question (not to mention well beyond the scope of the original question here) so isn't really something that can be answered on SO. Google about the topic, lots of people have blogged the pros and cons already.

Comment: Well, you know me... always one for the complex questions!